# DateTime format and calcaulting the difference in seconds in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying the below example on my learning process, can anyone please help me on below doubts,

1. How to format the datetime column with specific date format
2. How to find the time duration between execution start and stop in seconds

I have created the schema with below query,

```
    CREATE TABLE User (UserID int NOT NULL UNIQUE, Username Varchar(200), PRIMARY KEY (UserID));

    create table Process (ProcessID int NOT NULL UNIQUE, ProcessName varchar(100),LastModifiedDate datetime, LastModifiedByUser int not null UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY (ProcessID),
    FOREIGN KEY (LastModifiedByUser) REFERENCES User(UserID));

    create table session (SessionID int NOT NULL UNIQUE, processID int NOT NULL UNIQUE , startdatetime datetime , stopdatetime datetime, startedbyuser int NOT NULL UNIQUE , PRIMARY KEY (sessionid) , FOREIGN KEY (processid) REFERENCES process(ProcessID) , FOREIGN KEY (startedbyuser) REFERENCES user (UserID));


    INSERT INTO User (UserID, Username)VALUES ('1', "XXX");
    INSERT INTO User (UserID, Username)VALUES ('2', "YYY");
    INSERT INTO User (UserID, Username)VALUES ('3', "ZZZ");

    INSERT INTO Process (ProcessID, ProcessName, LastModifiedDate,LastModifiedByUser) VALUES ('100', "running the job", CAST(N'2012-06-18 10:34:09.000' AS DateTime) , '1');
    INSERT INTO Process (ProcessID, ProcessName, LastModifiedDate,LastModifiedByUser) VALUES ('101', "Forced stopped the application", CAST(N'2012-06-18 10:34:09.000' AS DateTime) , '3');

    INSERT INTO session (SessionID, processID, startdatetime,stopdatetime , startedbyuser) values ('1001', '101',CAST(N'2012-06-18 12:34:09.000' AS DateTime ), CAST(N'2012-06-18 23:34:09.000' AS DateTime), '1');
    INSERT INTO session (SessionID, processID, startdatetime,stopdatetime , startedbyuser) values ('1002', '100',CAST(N'2012-06-18 15:34:09.000' AS DateTime ), CAST(N'2012-06-18 17:34:09.000' AS DateTime), '3');
```

And tried to retrieve the data,

```
SELECT Process.ProcessID, session.startedbyuser , session.startdatetime, session.stopdatetime , Process.LastModifiedDate, process.LastModifiedByUser FROM Process INNER JOIN session ON Process.ProcessID=session.ProcessID;
```

Comment: Conversion functions, the things you need, are different in mysql and sql server. Do you need both?

Comment: Remove the schema screenshot and paste the actual TSQL code into the question

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I need to execute this query in SQL server

Comment: @Mazhar Edited with SQL code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to format the datetime column with specific date format

You're on SQL 2008 so you've really only got [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> How to find the time duration between execution start and stop in
>   seconds

For this you have [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT
    P.ProcessID
    ,S.startedbyuser
    ,[FormattedDateTime] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), S.startdatetime, 109)
    ,S.startdatetime
    ,S.stopdatetime
    ,P.LastModifiedDate
    ,Duration_in_Seconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND, S.startdatetime, S.stopdatetime)
    ,duration_as_time = CONVERT(TIME,stopdatetime-startdatetime) 
    ,P.LastModifiedByUser
FROM
    dbo.Process P
INNER JOIN  [dbo].[session] S ON P.ProcessID    = S.processID
```

Comment: The datediff will give you the difference in int (eg 2000). If you want a 00:03:45 version, use convert(time,endtime-starttime)

Comment: Is this a right way to do with Datediff ? SELECT Process.ProcessID, session.startedbyuser , session.startdatetime, session.stopdatetime , Process.LastModifiedDate,(SELECT DATEDIFF(second,session.startdatetime,session.stopdatetime)), process.LastModifiedByUser
FROM Process INNER JOIN session ON Process.ProcessID=session.ProcessID;

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Can you please let me know how to use convert in select query?

Comment: select convert(time,endtime-starttime) as duration from session

Comment: Thanks @Mazhar can you please let me know how to include convert to format the datetime with specific format in select query?

Comment: @Mazhar mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmmAM (or PM)--> Oct 2 2008 11:02:44:013AM